# Look up filters issue

Tags: lookup-filter

I've two fields say Country1__c and Country2__c both are look-up to same object say Country__c

Country__C has field called 'Continent__C' having value say Asia, Europe, Africa etc..

Now my requirement is- If some has selected Say Country France belonging to Continent 'Eurupe' in field Country1__c(look up to Country)
Then I want to restict for Country2__c, one should only be able to select countries of continent 'Europe' only

Is that possible using lookup Filters?

I was trying adding filter like --- Country2__c.Continent__c =  Country1__c.Continent__c  in lookup filter of Country2__c. But unfortunately not getting field Country1__c in its look up filter.

Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think you could achieve it with just lookup filters. However, you can have a similar result with a validation rule like

```
Country1__r.Continent__c != Country2.Continent__c
```

This would prevent users from selecting countries from different continents. I would also add the *Continent__c* column in the lookup field layout so that your users can see which countries they should select from (they can sort them by continent or even search the chosen continent directly in the lookup selection).